# Why do I need a WHERE clause in my insert statement when I have already have an UPDATE statement?

Tags: sql

Why do I need a WHERE clause in my INSERT statement when I already have an UPDATE statement? If I have an UPDATE statement with a WHERE clause, why do I need an INSERT statement with a WHERE clause, and vice-versa?

Comment: We cant have where clause in insert statement. What have u tried? Show us your code

Comment: @ Mari :- INSERT INTO supportContacts (details) VALUES ('admin') WHERE id = 2;

or

UPDATE supportContacts SET details = 'admin' where id = 2;

Comment: Ur insert statement is not valid. Did you try running it? Is it executing?

Comment: Are you running Oracle or SQL Server? - you've tagged both. In either case, your insert should not work like that.

Comment: Agree with @Mari. Insert always inserts a new row and will not accept a WHERE clause.

Comment: What's the meaning of a `where clause` in insert ?! the row is not there yet...

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`INSERT` statement do not have where clause. The basic syntax of `INSERT` is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (ColumnNames1, ....) VALUES (Values1, ....)
```

The only time an `INSERT` have a `WHERE` clause is when you are inserting from the result of select. `INSERT INTO ...SELECT` statement, eg

```
INSERT INTO tableName (ColumnNames1, ....)
SELECT ColumnNames1, ....
FROM tableNameN
WHERE ....
```

An `INSERT` statement inserts or adds new record on the table while, an `UPDATE` statement **only edits** the values of record(s) on the table.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I need a WHERE clause in my insert statement when I have already have an UPDATE 
>   statement?

Well, given that INSERT does not support a WHERE clause... your statement can only be answered with: Read a beginner book about SQL, because you do NOT need a WHERE clause in an INSERT statement.